# Chi-Square Degeneracy for Large Sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multivariate-analysis, large-data, anomaly-detection

(Forgive my hand-waving explanation) When discussing anomaly detection methods (for example), one possibility is comparing the distance of a point from a centroid: Given 100 samples $X_1,...,X_{100}$ and significance level $\alpha$, we can create a sphere around $\bar{X}$ using a $\chi^2$ critical value. Then, for a new sample $Y$, we can check whether it falls inside this sphere or not.

As sample size $n$ grows, this sphere becomes tighter - the "allowed" Mahalanobis distance becomes smaller and thus classical hypothesis testing tends to reject the null. I've once had a conference face-to-face chat with someone professor (can't recall his name) who claimed that $\chi^2$ becomes degenerate with large degrees of freedom. This makes sense, of course. It's kinda obvious that the overall variance grows faster than $\chi^2$ (or, in reverse angle, the the $\chi^2$ critical value decays faster and sharper than the sample variance).

This is kinda tricky, although it makes a lot of sense: I can't find any paper to cite on this argument, except for the [Fisher-Pearson exchange](http://www2.fiu.edu/~blissl/PearsonFisher.pdf) which doesn't suffice. Furthermore, I simply fail exemplify this argument by simulation: I've tried some ideas but they've all gone wrong. all I need to do is to show how variance grows faster than $\chi^2$ (or any other alternative which fits in your opinion).

Any ideas?

Comment: You ask about growth of "variance:" but what variance would this be, exactly, and what is the sense in which it might "grow"?

Comment: If we discuss univariate, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x-\bar{x})^2}$ grows (with $n$) faster than $\chi^2_{n-1}$ and equivalently $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(x-\bar{x})^2}$ decays slower than the relevant $\chi^2$ critical value

Comment: Could you explain how that could possibly happen?  Are you supposing the $X_i$ might be correlated, for instance, or drawn from a common distribution with infinite variance, or drawn from different distributions?